# "Lost connection to device" on specific hardware during web authentication

Tags: android, flutter, dart, authentication, web

I have an application that implement web authentication using flutter_web_auth 0.4.1 package.

When i test my implementation on a samsung smartphone, everything work like a charm. The Chrome browser launch on authentication website, after authentication i came back in my application and view is refreshed like i need.

But when i test my implementation on a Huawei tablet, just after chrome launch, i lost connection. After authenticating i came back in my application, but i can see that application is reloading (I can see splash screen) without saving token as i always came back to login screen.

Here is my implementation:

**Function that authenticate (called by an ElevatedButton onPressed event)** :

```
  authenticate() async {
    final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
        url: "https://xxxx.yyyy.eu/auth/login?authorize=yes",
        callbackUrlScheme: "com.example.zzzzzzzz");
    final token = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['token'] ?? '';

    // Save token
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString("token", token);

    refreshAfterAuthentication();
  }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" > 
    <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.example.zzzzzzzz" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Web redirection after authentication (Angular app)** :

```
window.location.href = 'com.example.zzzzzzzz://success?token=' + data.token;
```

As i lost connection, just after chrome launch, i can't see log in console about what is causing the application reload after redirecting to it.

Is there another way to debug this case ?

**Edit** :

Smartphone run under Android 9 and tablet under android 8. Is it possible that web auth can't be implemented on Android 8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding an exported attibute to activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`, like this :

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    <activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" android:exported="true"> 
        <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="com.example.andidoor" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Android reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported

Answer (score 0):

do you have internet permission in android manifist.xml?

```html
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

if the answer is yes I think you have to add timeOut to your request :

```
final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
        url: "https://xxxx.yyyy.eu/auth/login?authorize=yes",
        callbackUrlScheme: "com.example.zzzzzzzz").timeout(
      Duration(seconds: 5000),
    );
```

Comment: By default, in flutter debug mode, INTERNET permission is always ON, i will give try with timeout

Comment: @ E. Zahra The behavior is exactly the same with a timeout.